# Show feature classes as a checklist in a workspace in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, modelbuilder

In my model, I would like to show all the feature classes inside a file gdb as a "checklist", similar to how the tool dialog window for `Make Query Table` looks:

[image: Make Query Table dialog window]

So instead of the input being a table, and the field names are populated below so the user can select which fields are needed, I would like the input to be a file gdb and the feature classes inside it are populated in the window, so only the required feature classes can be selected. Is this possible inside modelbuilder via a tool or some Python code (maybe `ListFeatureClasses` but it must display the output)?

It would also be helpful to know what that type of window is called. I know the top section is the `Multiple Value` window, so what would the "checklist" window be called?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use the [Select Data](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000v6000000) tool and set the Child Data Element's "variable contains" property to "a list of values", allowing you select multiple children of a workspace.

[image: Child Data Element Properties]
[image: Model Tool Dialog]

Example output:

```
Executing: Model1 C:\GISData\linetest.gdb lines1
Start Time: Mon Oct 29 00:29:55 2012
Executing (Select Data): SelectData C:\GISData\linetest.gdb lines1
Start Time: Mon Oct 29 00:29:55 2012
Executing (Select Data): SelectData C:\GISData\linetest.gdb lines2
Executing (Select Data): SelectData C:\GISData\linetest.gdb lines2_intersect
Succeeded at Mon Oct 29 00:29:55 2012 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)
Executing (Get Count): GetCount C:\GISData\linetest.gdb\lines1
Start Time: Mon Oct 29 00:29:55 2012
Row Count = 11
Executing (Get Count): GetCount C:\GISData\linetest.gdb\lines2
Row Count = 13
Executing (Get Count): GetCount C:\GISData\linetest.gdb\lines2_intersect
Row Count = 23
Succeeded at Mon Oct 29 00:29:56 2012 (Elapsed Time: 1.00 seconds)
Succeeded at Mon Oct 29 00:29:56 2012 (Elapsed Time: 1.00 seconds)
```

One downside of this you might have noticed is that the tools within the model are not executed in series but rather in parallel (sort of) when you do this, it's the same problem as described in [Does Calculate Value (Model Only Tool) work correctly in tools run in Batch?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36891/does-calculate-value-model-only-tool-work-correctly-in-tools-run-in-batch)