# Passing each parsed file name to next tool in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder

I cannot get the Parse Path tool to pass each file name to the next tool. In the example shown, the Raster to Ascii tool will take the first entry in the 'filename' variable list as part of the output name. But when it runs the next iteration, the Raster to Ascii tool uses some generic file naming convention. 'filename' is set as a precondition for the R2A tool.

Example:
raster1.tif
raster2.tif
Run the Model in Batch mode, using tifs as parameters.
1st output = raster1_asc.txt
2nd output = RastTo_rast.txt <--- this is wrong.

[image: Model Builder running as Batch]

Summary: Raster to Ascii tool sucessfully uses the filename variable as inline variable as part of the output file name. However, the the Raster to Ascii tool uses a generic naming convention for the following files (running Model as Batch).

Does anyone have an insight as to why this is happening?

Comment: Try calling %filename% in the raster to ascii output without making filename a precondition.

Comment: Perhaps review [**Does Calculate Value (Model Only Tool) work correctly in tools run in Batch?**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36891/does-calculate-value-model-only-tool-work-correctly-in-tools-run-in-batch/36900#36900) - apparently custom tools from ModelBuilder that run fine standalone don't always work from the Batch Grid - this is currently treated by Esri as a Known Limit but its one that I think they should try to address - your Question reminds me of this one.

Comment: @Aaron - Tried that, no difference.

Comment: @PolyGeo - if I'm reading the post right, it seems like that's what's happening here. The same filename variable is used the second time, and the tool avoids overwriting the previous file by using a generic name. Maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps review [Does Calculate Value (Model Only Tool) work correctly in tools run in Batch?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36891/does-calculate-value-model-only-tool-work-correctly-in-tools-run-in-batch/36900#36900)

Apparently custom tools from ModelBuilder that run fine standalone don't always work from the Batch Grid.

This is [NIM053898](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDUzODk4) and is currently treated by Esri as a Known Limit.  However, I think it should be addressed with priority because being able to use ModelBuilder to create a tool that can simply be run in Batch is very appealing.